# Create concatenated array based on property in an array of objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash, underscore.js

I have some data that is an array of objects like so:

```
let employees = 
[
    {
        emp_id: "1",
        course_data : [
            {
                info: "info",
                for: "emp_id_1"
            },
            {
                info: "more_info",
                for: "emp_id_1 "
            },
            {
                info: "even_more_info",
                for: "emp_id_1 "
            },

        ],

        emp_id: "2",
        course_data : [
            {
                info: "info",
                for: "emp_id_2"
            },
            {
                info: "more_info",
                for: "emp_id_2 "
            },
            {
                info: "even_more_info",
                for: "emp_id_2 "
            },

        ],
    },
];
```

I want to create a conatenated array of objects from the `course_data` property all objects in the parent array have. In other words, I'd like to have my data in the following format so that I can run `_.groupBy()` on the it:

```
let concatenated_array = [
            {
                info: "info",
                for: "emp_id_1"
            },
            {
                info: "more_info",
                for: "emp_id_1 "
            },
            {
                info: "even_more_info",
                for: "emp_id_1 "
            },

            {
                info: "info",
                for: "emp_id_2"
            },
            {
                info: "more_info",
                for: "emp_id_2 "
            },
            {
                info: "even_more_info",
                for: "emp_id_2 "
            },

        ]
```

I'm thinking something like `unionWith`, but I'm not sure. Is this possible in lodash?

Comment: Your original data is invalid in its present form, since it has multiple properties with the same key (multiple `emp_id`s, for instance). Assuming that's a typo, and you actually have an array of individual objects, there are a few duplicates on Stack Overflow. What research have you done and attempts made based on that research?

Comment: But with lodash you're looking for [\_.flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatMap) (`_.flatMap(employees, 'course_data')`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with only javascript tools, like that:

```
employees.map(empl => empl.course_data).flat()
```

Comment: Or just use [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) which is slightly more efficient than calling both methods separately.